# Does not display data in linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have Linq which counts the goods, the problem is that the names that I pass, they do not work
ProductName, CompanyName, CustomerName,
Maybe there is a error in Linq?
It produces many anonymous methods that have these fields, but after ToList() everything does not work

[image]

[image]

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SalesReportItem>> GetReportData(DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd)
            {
                dateStart = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
                var context = await _contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
                var queryable = context.SalesTransactionRecords.Join(
                        context.Products,
                        salesTransactionRecords => salesTransactionRecords.ProductId,
                        products => products.Id,
                        (salesTransactionRecords, products) =>
                            new
                            {
                                salesTransactionRecords,
                                products
                            })
                    .Join(context.Companies,
                        combinedEntry => combinedEntry.salesTransactionRecords.CompanyId,
                        company => company.Id,
                        (combinedEntry, company) => new
                        {
                            combinedEntry,
                            company
                        })
                    .Join(context.VendorCustomers,
                        combinedEntryAgain => combinedEntryAgain.combinedEntry.salesTransactionRecords.CustomerId,
                        vendorCustomer => vendorCustomer.Id,
                        (combinedEntryAgain, vendorCustomer) => new
                        {
                            CompanyName = combinedEntryAgain.company.Name,
                            CustomerName = vendorCustomer.Name,
                            ProductId = combinedEntryAgain.combinedEntry.products.Id,
                            ProductName = combinedEntryAgain.combinedEntry.products.Name,
                            combinedEntryAgain.combinedEntry.salesTransactionRecords.MovementType,
                            combinedEntryAgain.combinedEntry.salesTransactionRecords.Period,
                            combinedEntryAgain.combinedEntry.salesTransactionRecords.Quantity,
                            combinedEntryAgain.combinedEntry.salesTransactionRecords.Amount,
                        }).Where(x => x.Period >= dateStart && x.Period <= dateEnd)
                    .GroupBy(combinedEntryAgain => new
                        {
                            combinedEntryAgain.ProductId,
                            combinedEntryAgain.ProductName,
                            combinedEntryAgain.CompanyName,
                            combinedEntryAgain.CustomerName,
                        }
                    ).Select(x => new SalesReportItem
                    {
                        ProductId = x.Key.ProductId,
                        Quantity = x.Sum(a => a.Quantity),
                        Amount = x.Sum(x => (x.MovementType == TableMovementType.Income ? x.Amount : -(x.Amount)))
                    });
    
    
             var items = await queryable.ToListAsync();
    
                return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SalesReportItem>>(items);
            }
```

Comment: In your final Select, you select just three fields - maybe you need to specify those others as well?

Comment: Try debugging and inspecting.

Comment: Hans Keﬆing, you were right, I didn't make the last selection correctly, I'll try to finish it and send it as an example

Answer (score 2):

my mistake was that I did not specify the fields in the select, otherwise everything is buzzing, the upper code is working

```
Select(x => new SalesReportItem
                    {
                        ProductId = x.Key.ProductId,
                        ProductName = x.Key.ProductName,
                        CompanyName = x.Key.CompanyName,
                        CustomerName = x.Key.CustomerName,
                        Quantity = x.Sum(x => (x.MovementType == TableMovementType.Income ? x.Quantity : - x.Quantity)),
                        Amount = x.Sum(x => (x.MovementType == TableMovementType.Income? x.Amount: - x.Amount))
                    });
```

Thanks for the help
Hans Keﬆing